# Simplest j2ee basic authentication

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, basic-authentication, rad

I am in WebSphere 8/RAD 9, and trying to write the simplest, most self-contained basic authentication for my app.  We have alot of complex apps using single sign-on and LDAP and so forth.  But we're also writing a little diagnostic tool for our own internal use that we want to host on the same boxes.  We will be denying access from the outside, but we're also going to password protect it with a single common uid/pwd shared among the team...just to be extra sure we keep the rif-raff out.

But as weird as it is to say it, this simple thing seems harder than the complicated apps.  How can I get my webapp to have a self-contained basic auth with a simple one or two user password scheme hard-coded into the application?  I did the following in web.xml, but I am not sure where the user list itself goes, or how to bind those users to this viewer role.

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>secure</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>viewer</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>file</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
  <role-name>viewer</role-name>
</security-role>
```

I just want it self-contained in this ear so it goes wherever the ear goes.

Answer (score 0):

User list is taken form the repository configured in WAS. In this way your application is protected no matter, if server is configured with LDAP, file based registry or custom.

It is much better and more flexible than trying to hardcode registry inside your app, so I'd suggest you going that way. More over you will be able to create users and groups via WebSphere web admin console, and map these users to security roles in your application.

Take a look at example in the [WebSphere Security redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247660.html).

Answer (score 0):

After you deploy that app, go to the administrative console, select the application, select "security role to user/group mapping", then select whatever users/groups should be associated withe the "viewer" role.  Those users will need to be defined to WebSphere (that's separate, under "Users and Groups" in the console.)   You might need to change the realm-name to "default".

If you don't want to use WebSphere's security at all for some reason, then remove the security constraint and implement your own security (could be as simple as a password challenge) in your application.  You'll give up the auditing and logging you'd get with WebSphere security though.